# cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('u32') according to the rule 'safe'

Tags: python, arrays

This is my function `logistic (x,w)`

```
def logistic(x, w):
  return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-x.dot(w)))

w = 2 * np.random.ranf((NDIM, 1)) - 1

def score(matrix, w):
   y= np.matrix ([':,0])
   X= np.matrix ([':,1:])
```

when I apply :

```
pred = logistic(X, w)
```

I get the error:

```
" cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('u32') according to the rule 'safe' "
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code, pls correct it first.

Comment: please i'm not familiar with python can u show me the error ?

Comment: please add two other spaces before the first return !

Comment: take a look at this link before: https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html